# Removing bunch of commas from the end of all lines in CSV

Tags: csv, arff

I need to turn a `csv` into an `arff` file but when i try to do it through the `ARFFViewer` form `weka` I get the following error:

```
"java.io.IOException: wrong number of values. Read 5, expected 6, read Token[EOL], line 2 encountered line: 2"
```

I've investigated this and what I have found is that I have a comma at the end of each line in my `csv`, the problem here is that is not one comma, there are a bunch of commas and not the same quantity in each line of the file and i have 10.000 lines so what could I do here?

Example of `csv` line:

```
chicken,tropical fruit,domestic eggs,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

pot plants,domestic eggs,diapers,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

specialty bar,white bread,diapers,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Examples of other ending commas:

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a VI editor  `:%s/,,//g`  Search for `,,` and replace with